# Custom sort by property

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a method in Python for sorting, which takes a parameter `alarm.__dict__['severity']`. How can I access the severity parameter another way?

My sort function is:

```
sorted(alarm_list, key=lambda alarm: alarm.__dict__['severity'])
```

Is there any other way in which I can get the severity parameter?

Comment: You're trying to sort by alarm.severity? What type is `alarm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) instead of `__dict__`:

```
sorted(alarm_list, key=lambda alarm: getattr(alarm, 'severity'))
```

However, it seems like this would work just as well:

```
sorted(alarm_list, key=lambda alarm: alarm.severity)
```

Both examples assume that `alarm` always has a `severity`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!